# Nhibernate Criteria Query with Join

Tags: nhibernate, join, criteria, distinct

I am looking to do the following using an NHibernate Criteria Query

I have "Product"s which has 0 to Many "Media"s

A product can be associated with 1 to Many ProductCategories

These use a table in the middled to create the join

> **ProductCategories**
>   Id
>   Title
>
> **ProductsProductCategories**
>   ProductCategoryId
>   ProductId
>
> **Products**
>   Id
>   Title
>
> **ProductMedias**
>   ProductId
>   MediaId
>
> **Medias**
>   Id
>   MediaType

I need to implement a criteria query to return All Products in a ProductCategory and the top 1 associated Media or no media if none exists.

So although for example a "T Shirt" may have 10 Medias associated, my result should be something similar to this

Product.Id    Product.Title    MediaId
1 T Shirt 21
2 Shoes Null
3 Hat 43

I have tried the following solutions using JoinType.LeftOuterJoin

> 1) productCriteria.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);

This hasnt worked as the transform is done code side and as I have .SetFirstResult() and .SetMaxResults() for paging purposes it wont work.

> 2) .SetProjection(
>       Projections.Distinct(
>           Projections.ProjectionList() 
>           .Add(Projections.Alias(Projections.Property("Id"), "Id")) 
>           ...
>      .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean());

This hasn't worked as I cannot seem to populate a value for Medias.Id in the projections. (Similar to [nHibernate Criteria API Projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036116/nhibernate-criteria-api-projections))

Any help would be greatly appreciated